# написать в разных файлах js/html fancybox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, fancybox

Доброго времени суток.
Имеется код например такой

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.fancybox.min.css">
    <script src="jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <a class="youtube" data-fancybox href="https://www.youtube.com/"
     data-width="600" data-height="300">
        YouTube video
    </a>
    <br>

</body>
</html>
```

Я с ***js*** почти не знаком, по этому у меня ступор...
Как это разбить на **html** и ***js*** файлы, так, чтобы ***js*** кода не было в **html** соответственно, чтобы весь fancybox был в ***js***. Помогите пожалуйста, смотрел пишут установить ещё 100500 библиотек... 
очень нужно
Может искал не так, или не там, но ответа без установки ещё доп библиотек не нашёл, предлагали npm-node js-webpack, но я с npm тоже не знаком, есть вариант без них обойтись?

Если подскажете, как будет выглядеть итоговый ***js***  в данном примере буду очень благодарен.

Comment: У вас и так все разбито по файлам

Comment: Вам нужно чтобы весь js был в одном файле?

Comment: Да, мне нужно, чтобы кода fancybox/js не было в html, ну то есть script.js просто подключался к html, а внутри js был бы весь fancybox

Comment: У вас сейчас так и есть, если вы имеет ввиду все скрипты в один файл, ну создайте новый файл в ручную, скопируйте в него все скрипты, а потом этот файл подключите к странице

Comment: что именно мне нужно написать в script.js, который я буду подключать к index.html? просто мне нужно, чтобы из блока body на html странице осталось по идее что-то вроде <a  class="youtube" >YouTube video</a> и всё

Comment: я написал выше что нужно сделать